# Infinite loop error when inserting more than one\newtcbinputlisting setting

Tags: listings, tcbinputlisting

I was attempting to generate different programming languages code snippets to highlight the different syntax in different programming languages like: Python, Matlab and C++ (more to be added later).

In the code given below, I am getting the error:

`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\cl@chapter ->\cl@chapter 
                          \@elt {matlab}
l.73 ...code,number within=chapter]{\inputcppcode}
                                                  [3][]{listing options={lan...`

Can you tell me how to get rid of this error to get my file to compile correctly?

Thanks.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}
\newcommand{\codeimgpy}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}}$}
\newcommand{\codeimgcpp}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{cppcode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimgpy~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
        after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{listing options={style=Matlab-editor},%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#2},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=cppcode,list inside=cppcode,number within=chapter]{\inputcppcode}[3][]{listing options={language=C++},%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimgcpp~#2},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut C++ Code~\thecppcode~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,language=C++},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries C++ Code~\thecppcode:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{codeblock}

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}

% https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/add-numbers
\inputcppcode{Example C++ Code}{cppcodex.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the error in the much smaller https://gist.github.com/moewew/90f5a487685014daee58617d37a9a571. The error goes away if I remove the `number within=chapter` from the second definition ... seems the bug is hiding there.

Comment: Come to think of it `article` does not have sections, so the behaviour of `number within=chapter` is probably undefined. If I go with something like `number within=section`, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: @moewe, Thanks for your inputs.  I think you found the solution.  If I change the document to `book`, it works.  Thank you!

Comment: Indeed the same error can be reproduced with https://gist.github.com/moewew/90f5a487685014daee58617d37a9a571#file-addtoreset-tex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problematic code is the `numberwithin=chapter` in the definitions. The `article` document class does not have a counter `chapter` since it does not have `\chapter`s and so resetting by `chapter` is not really a well-defined concept.

The same issue can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=a, number within=chapter]{\inputverba}[1]{listing file={#1}}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=b, number within=chapter]{\inputverbb}[1]{listing file={#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.x}
Lorem
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\inputverba{sample.x}
\inputverbb{sample.x}
\end{document}
```

and ultimately by tracing back what `number within` does also with

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{a}{chapter}%
\@addtoreset{b}{chapter}%
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

This error occurs when you want to `\@addtoreset` a second time to a counter that does not exist.

Incidentally, `\@removefromreset` has a bit of error checking here, according to [`source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (p. 147, file m)

> Even through this is internal and the programmer should know what he/she is doing we test here if counter `#2` is defined.

but no such error checking is done for `\@addtoreset`.

The solution is to either pick an existing counter to reset with, i.e. `number within=section`, or to use a document class with `\chapter`s, i.e. `report` or `book`.